# Straight or Drop handlebars?

Tags: road-bike, handlebars

Can someone explain to me the pros/cons of drop or straight? I've never used drops before and have never owned a good road bike (just cheap mountain bikes) - I am buying a decent single speed soon and unsure if I am better to go with straight or drop bars.

I am not an experienced cyclist and the bike will be used for fun/commute mainly (no on-road riding where I am weaving between cars or anything, cycleways)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Drop bars

The main advantage of drop bars is that you have a variety of positions for your hands, giving you options to make you more aerodynamic or just have a change if you get a bit sore in one spot. Additionally, having your hands 'pointing forward' is a more neutral position for your shoulders, where flat bars cause them to rotate outwards.

Related questions:

- [What are the positions on drop bars called?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/8852/1588)
- [How to use drop bars properly?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/5251/1588)

### Flat bars

The main advantage of flat bars is that you are always in the optimal position to grab the brakes and gears. Additionally, flat bars can be wider, providing more control.

### Other bar types

[Different kinds of Handlebars](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/1195/1588)

Comment: As long as you stick to the hoods and drops, and leave the tops for things like climbing hills, you should always be in a good position to use your brakes. Although there is less braking power from the hoods, you should still be able to stop relatively quickly if your brakes are set up properly.